# Swiching the Stackpanel in single ViewModel Using Back/Next Button WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF, with Form with multiple user required questions. I have created 2 Stackpanels which have similar layout, first form (Stackpanel) will let the user to fill up information.While second form (Stackpanel) would be preview form for the user before he submits.

## **XAML Code**

```
<Window x:Class="NinjaLIB.View.SSOEMWarrantyButtonExtension"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NinjaLIB.View"
        xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
        lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture="en"
        lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="NinjaLIB"
        lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Resources"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=RMAView, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Request RMA" Height="600" Width="1000"
        xmlns:mvvmlight="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
     xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:NinjaLIB.Converter"

     WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"  ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <!--<i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
            <mvvmlight:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GetRMAWindowClosed}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>-->
        <!--<i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <mvvmlight:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GetWarrantyWindowLoaded}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>-->
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Some QUestions asked to the User-->
      <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <!--View Form Fill-->
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewState}" Value="FormFillViewState">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
          **<!--Some QUestions asked to the User-->**
           </StackPanel >
            </ScrollViewer>
        **<!--View Preview Form-->**
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewState}" Value = "PreviewFillState" >
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
        **<!--Some QUestions asked to the User-->**
               </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--Buttons-->
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Next"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsConnected}"

                                        Command="{Binding NextCommandBtn}"
                                        FontWeight="Normal"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                        
                                        Height="30"
                                        Width="80"
                                        Margin="780,0,0,2"
                                        Padding="3,0"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Back"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsConnected}"

                                        Command="{Binding BackCommandBtn}"
                                        FontWeight="Normal"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                        
                                        Height="30"
                                        Width="80"
                                        Margin="420,0,0,2"
                                        Padding="3,0"/>

  </Window>
```

==============

**View Model Section Code**

==============

private RMAViewModel RMAView;

```
private readonly ResourceManager rm;
public RMAViewModel()
{
    rm = new ResourceManager("NinjaLIB.Properties.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}

//Properties for the Window (Date and Text) for FormFillViewState
//Properties for the Window (Date and Text) for PreviewFillState
```

==============

I wanted some help with view Model code, where if I click ***NextCommandBtn*** all the data will appear as filled up form from first stackpanel view and when I select ***BackCommandBtn*** i can edit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it like this:

You have two views (StackPanels) and only one can be displayed at a time.

So in your view-model, you need a property that tells you which view is active. A simple `bool` property for each view would work. Since there are only two views, you could technically just use a single property, but using two will make your XAML data binding a little easier.

Examples:

- IsFormActive
- IsPreviewActive

In your XAML, you need to control the `Visibility` property of your two `StackPanel` controls based on your IsFormActive and IsPreviewActive properties in your view-model. You can do this with a value converter, specifically the [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=netframework-4.8).

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsFormActive, 
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}">
  ...
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsPreviewActive, 
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}">
  ...
</StackPanel>
```

And back in your view-model you can control the state of IsFormActive and IsPreviewActive when the next and back buttons are clicked, etc.

I hope this helps you get an idea of how to proceed.